# laravel get error of Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

In Laravel I have got this error, while inserting a record in my MongoDB database.

> Call to a member function prepare() on null

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{

  public function create()
  {
    return view('addemployee');
  }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee->firstName = $request->get('firstName');
    $employee->middleName = $request->get('middleName');
    $employee->lastName = $request->get('lastName');
    $employee->gender = $request->get('gender');
    $employee->city = $request->get('city');
    $employee->localAddress = $request->get('localAddress');
    $employee->permanentAddress = $request->get('permanentAddress');
    $employee->emailAddress = $request->get('emailAddress');
    $employee->mobileNumber = $request->get('mobileNumber');
    $employee->email = $request->get('email');
    $employee->department = $request->get('department');
    $employee->designation = $request->get('designation');
    $employee->save();

    return redirect('addemployee')->with('Success', 'Data Inserted Successfully!');

  }
}
```

This is my Employee Model Class:

```php
<?php
namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Employee extends Eloquent
{
  protected $connection = 'mongodb';
  protected $collection = 'employee';
  protected $fillable = [
    'firstName',
    'middleName',
    'lastName',
    'gender',
    'city',
    'localAddress',
    'parmanentAddress',
    'emailAddress',
    'mobileNumber',
    'email',
    'department',
    'designation'
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 25):

***Make Sure***

- the collection exists in the database
- Your model extends `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model` and not Model

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Node extends Eloquent
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This should resolve the issue if using [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package:

In `config/auth` make sure to have `model` value correctly set *if not using default `User` model location*:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User\User::class,
    ],
```

Next, your `User` model class should extend correct `Authenticable` (from the package):

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
...
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject { ... }
```

If everything else (guard, etc.) was configured right according to docs, it should work without any issue.

Comment: This line saved my day:
```use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;```

But for those guyz using Laravel 10x, use this instead:
```use MongoDB\Laravel\Auth\User as Authenticatable;``` assuming you are using the Jensengers lib now owned by MongoDb: ***mongodb/laravel-mongodb***

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [`mongodb/laravel-mongodb`](https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/laravel-mongodb) make sure you are extending your model from MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model;

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you wrote `protected $collection` instead of `protected $table`.

By the way, this as probably no link with your error, but you wrote *parmanentAddress* instead of *permanentAddress* in your `$fillable` property. This may throw an other error since you are updating this field as well in your Controller.

**Fixed Employee Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Employee extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $table = 'employee';

    protected $fillable = [
        'firstName',
        'middleName',
        'lastName',
        'gender',
        'city',
        'localAddress',
        'permanentAddress',
        'emailAddress',
        'mobileNumber',
        'email',
        'department',
        'designation'
    ]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for draw my attention to my Spelling mistake but it is not important now, And i am using MongoDB so it has to be $collection not $table. @P.Ellul

Comment: Oops, I didn't realized you are extending something else than the original Model.

Comment: Show u know the answer.
i apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

Call to a member function prepare() on null in file /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 359

In my case, I had changed the domain but hadn't updated APP_URL in .env to the new domain.